# Флэш либо слайдер в зависимости от поддержки JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

У меня есть два слайдера: один на JS, второй на Flash. Надо, чтобы при входе на сайт изначально отображался флеш, (т.е. у дива, в котором слайдер сделан на JS, прописал я `style="display:none;"`), а если включен JS, то див с флешем принимал значение `display:none;` а у слайдера на JS наоборот `display:block;`

Answer (score 1):

Ну и сделайте скрипт на js, который меняет display у флеш дива, и у js дива. Если js отключен, то ничего не будет.